# How do I scale decode a Vec<u8> within an ink smart contract?

Tags: ink, decode

This is within my smart contract's module:

```rust
        // THIS IS BEING USED: use ink::prelude::vec::Vec;
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn test_encoding(&mut self) -> Result<u32, ZeitDAOError> {
            let mut x: Vec<u8> = scale::Encode::encode(&RuntimeCall::TestCall);

            // There is an error here
            match <u32 as scale::Decode>::decode(&mut x) {
                Ok(value) => Ok(value),
                Err(_) => Err(ZeitDAOError::ErrorDecodingProposalData)
            }
        }
```

There is a compiler error when passing in `&mut x` to the decode function:

```
the trait bound `Vec<u8>: Input` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `Input`:
  IoReader<R>
  AppendZerosInput<'a, T>
  TrailingZeroInput<'a>
  &'a [u8]
```

I assume this is because the ink Vec is not the typical library's Vec? I'm unsure how otherwise to use the decoding method, or if there is a method at all. Or do I misunderstand how `Decode::decode` works?

Thank you!